# Input element unusable in IE7?

Tags: css, input, internet-explorer-7, stylesheet

For some reason our website's input elements are unusable in IE7:

```
https://hillcrestanimalhospital.co.uk/store/customer/account/login/
```

There are a number of stylesheets in operation and I am not sure on the best way of narrowing down which one is causing the problem.

The inputs seem to work perfectly in IE6, IE8, Firefox and Chrome.

If anyone has any idea on the best way to narrow down this issue it would be greatly appreciated!

**Actual Error**

The text boxes cannot have anything entered into them. They cannot be clicked and focused. The hover effect doesn't even work.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce it as IE9 with IE7 compatibility mode shows no problems, but could you try adding zoom: 1 to your css properties for inputs?

Comment: Which input elements exactly? The buttons, the text fields or all of them?

Comment: Works fine in IE7 compatibility mode (*from ie8 and ie9*)

Comment: How are they not usable. Cant they be focused. Do they not send the correct data to the server? ...

Comment: It's interesting that it won't show in compatibility mode in IE9. I have checked and my version of IE7 is set to 100% zoom - is that the same as zoom: 1?

Comment: Sorry - the text boxes cannot have anything entered into them. They cannot be clicked and focused. The hover effect doesn't even work.

Comment: I used IE9 in various browser/document modes but wasn't able to reproduce the issue. Perhaps someone else with IE7 can confirm and help out. Otherwise it may help if you tell us what exactly you mean by "unusuable": is that disabled? Or hidden? Or... ?

Comment: All inputs work fine in my IE7 on my work laptop

Comment: Hmm, this is strange. Does the following link work fine on your work laptop in IE7? http://hillcrestanimalhospital.co.uk/store/dogs/dog-accessories

Comment: I'm using IE 7.0.5730.13 and everything works fine, the only difference is that the on focus green border does not work, but i'm able to enter text and log in (and get `Invalid login or password.` back)

Comment: hillcrestanimalhospital.co.uk/store/dogs/dog-accessories work OK except that the breadcrumb/show options bar display is screwed up

Comment: Works for me in IETester on Win7, but (unrelated) the font is really hard to read in all browsers, way too small, lightly colored, and the serifs don't help either.

Comment: Yeah, the fonts are the next big change - switching to something universal like Times New Roman.

Comment: @Wesley Murch - could you send me a screenshot of how the fonts look on your browser? I know the font is difficult to read but font size has never been commented on before.

Comment: @dannymcc: The `input`s work fine for me with genuine IE7 v7.0.5730.13 on XP.

Comment: It's a combination of font choice, size, and color. It's really really tight, I would say almost half the size it should be. I would send a screen shot but didn't see your email address in your profile or website, and it's not related to the question so I'm not posting it here. FYI it's the same in IE and FF.

Comment: ok, I think I'm going to find a designer who's far better at font stacks than I am! Thanks!

Comment: Yep, people really like to be able to read the text :) Serif fonts are hard to get right, and IMO any **Times** variant is a poor choice in general.

Comment: I've just tested it in Firefox 4 on Windows XP Pro SP3 and it looks fine. I'm struggling to match the complaints of everyone else.

Comment: Reading these comments it is very likely that something specific to your setup is causing this. Try disabling addons, look at the site on a colleague's PC, etc. Also perhaps extend the original question with some info from the Dev Tools (hit F12 to pop them up) and tell us what browser/document mode IE7 is running in.

Answer (score 0):

I used IE8 in IE7 compatibility mode and it did work for me, I do think tho, the names of the inputs could be a problem, have you tried changing them from login[password] to someting lke login-pass, I'm just speculating here, but IE7 could be having a problem reading those.

Cheers,
Leo